# How to parse output of unknown type in Julia

Tags: parsing, julia

I am running a function from an external library here:
https://github.com/baggepinnen/SingularSpectrumAnalysis.jl

When running, I get this output printed in the console:

```
LinearAlgebra.SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}
U factor:
3465×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.0176092   0.0162669   -0.0286626   …  -0.0123348   -0.00889247    0.0149834
 -0.0176079   0.023189    -0.00313753      0.0234491   -0.000954835   0.0237124
 -0.0175925   0.0216939    0.0187119       0.0418525   -0.0296555     0.0665848
 -0.0175613   0.0146738    0.0288932      -0.0266382    0.0127913     0.00602873
 -0.0175472   0.0072105    0.0349358       0.0225667   -0.0167306    -0.02098
 -0.0175337  -3.25703e-5   0.0304511   …  -0.0229247   -0.00725249   -0.00814757
 -0.0175243  -0.0070557    0.0154106       0.0424862   -0.0206749    -0.0115423
  ⋮                                    ⋱                             
 -0.0124291   0.0454897   -0.0153655      -0.019238     0.00716989    0.00251159
 -0.0122423   0.0435812   -0.0148046   …  -0.0139234   -0.0187464     0.00739847
 -0.0121735   0.0346687    0.00278444     -0.00218233   0.0110443    -0.00929289
 -0.0121211   0.0290382    0.0110726       0.0107806   -0.00106763    0.0317442
 -0.0120607   0.0194982    0.0217969       0.00578442  -0.0117156    -0.00232344
 -0.0120144   0.0126667    0.0164779      -0.0106475    0.00061507   -0.00797532
singular values:
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 23396.412954604883
    89.77233712912785
    22.739080907231845
     6.7695870707469386
     1.3883392478470917
     2.8068174835480837e-12
     8.400039642654283e-13
     8.317837915706779e-13
     8.065049690243271e-13
     7.945414181455442e-13
Vt factor:
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.316135   -0.316298    -0.316323   …  -0.316206   -0.31614    -0.315936
  0.408793    0.414593     0.333553      -0.33494    -0.41203    -0.407189
  0.363599    0.306612     0.0442128      0.0537767   0.309203    0.350534
 -0.314074   -0.183525     0.255186      -0.246725    0.186592    0.323551
 -0.295283   -0.0484189    0.451627       0.462796   -0.0426143  -0.315369
  0.455353   -0.378881    -0.296744   …   0.171696    0.409193   -0.445054
 -0.326408    0.586176    -0.435839       0.420663   -0.0126025  -0.143472
  0.114133    0.0540144   -0.485488      -0.155216   -0.293115    0.27703
 -0.0714588   0.00900755   0.0450054     -0.018732   -0.13437     0.165802
  0.287902   -0.328451     0.0436344      0.528208   -0.571383    0.290639
```

How do I parse this output to get the "U factor:", "singular values:" and "Vt factor:" output as arrays I can work with in a notebook?

I've tried indexing by position and by name (`[1]` or `["U factor"]`). Both result in errors such as this:

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::LinearAlgebra.SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::Int64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a part of a standard library, so it can be found in documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.svd

Output is only visual representation of the data, so it can't be used to access data programmatically. You should use docs or introspection functions like `fieldnames` to understand how to work with the object. In this case, you should use fields `U`, `S` and `Vt` of an `SVD` object.

Comment: According to the docs you can also iterate, so you can presumably do `(U, S, V) = svd(...)`